# How do I use UserDefaults with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, swiftui

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
@State var settingsConfiguration: Settings
    struct Settings {
        var passwordLength: Double = 20
        var moreSpecialCharacters: Bool = false
        var specialCharacters: Bool = false
        var lowercaseLetters: Bool = true
        var uppercaseLetters: Bool = true
        var numbers: Bool = true
        var space: Bool = false
    }
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Password Length: \(Int(settingsConfiguration.passwordLength))")
                    Spacer()
                    Slider(value: $settingsConfiguration.passwordLength, from: 1, through: 512)
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.moreSpecialCharacters) {
                    Text("More Special Characters")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.specialCharacters) {
                    Text("Special Characters")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.space) {
                    Text("Spaces")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.lowercaseLetters) {
                    Text("Lowercase Letters")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.uppercaseLetters) {
                    Text("Uppercase Letters")
                }
                Toggle(isOn: $settingsConfiguration.numbers) {
                    Text("Numbers")
                }
                Spacer()
                }
                .padding(.all)
                .frame(width: 500, height: 500)
  }
}
```

So I have all this code here and I want to use UserDefaults to save settings whenever a switch is changed or a slider is slid and to retrieve all this data when the app launches but I have no idea how I would go about using UserDefaults with SwiftUI (Or UserDefaults in general, I've just started looking into it so I could use it for my SwiftUI app but all the examples I see are for UIKit and when I try implementing them in SwiftUI I just run into a ton of errors).

Comment: Have you looked into `@EnvironmentObject`? Seems like it's part of the replacement for something so... `UIKit`. The other is scene-related versus app-related. (As in SceneDelegate versus AppDelegate.) As for *"...UserDefaults in general..."*? Maybe you need to ask one question at a time? Learn `UIKit` and `UserDefaults` first, then how to make it `SwiftUI`?

Comment: @dfd that's not really a helpful comment. It's perfectly valid for someone to start making apps for Apple platforms right now, starting with recommended technologies, and get lost since the documentation is incomplete. I don't think it's good to tell someone to go learn the old thing that's going away so they can do it their the new recommended way

Comment: When phrased like that (create a test app to learn), yes that's wonderful advice. I read your 2019 comment as advising to use UIKit instead of SwiftUI for this project, since SmushyTaco hadn't yet learned UserDefaults. As an aside, though, there are aspects of UserDefaults (like how it works with Combine) which work very well in SwiftUI but have nearly zero examples in UIKit

Answer (score 56):

The approach from caram is in general ok but there are so many problems with the code that SmushyTaco did not get it work. Below you will find an "Out of the Box" working solution.

#### 1. UserDefaults propertyWrapper

```
import Foundation
import Combine

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T
    
    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

#### 2. UserSettings class

```
final class UserSettings: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @UserDefault("ShowOnStart", defaultValue: true)
    var showOnStart: Bool {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. SwiftUI view

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var settings = UserSettings()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Toggle(isOn: $settings.showOnStart) {
            Text("Show welcome text")
        }
        if settings.showOnStart{
            Text("Welcome")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `import Combine` or you will get errors.

Comment: Nice, thanks!

One question though:
How can I access the user default outside of SwiftUI code?
I'm getting `Unknown attribute 'ObservedObject'` and I don't want to `import SwiftUI` in my non-ui classes.

Comment: i use same code  but  when i set UserDefault Value on beginning till end it same.  i update value  but it not getting change in the UserDefault.

Comment: Can anyone explain why do we need Property wrapper in 1 and why can't we use @Published in 2?

Comment: With propertyWrapper you can define your own custom Property Wrapper. Since we already use the UserDefault we can not use an additional Published. Thats why we use a willSet { objectWillChange.send() }  to get the Published behavior back.

Comment: @MarcT. Thanks for the response. I am using `@EnvironmentObject` for user settings page. And anytime I change a setting, the whole view refreshes.

Comment: It seems neither iOS 14 `@AppStorage` nor your solution works when the user defaults key is not actually bound to anything on screen, but instead used to recompute some other value that's displayed on screen.

Comment: do you actually need to define "objectWillChange"?

Its gets synthesized automatically.

Answer (score 36):

Starting from Xcode 12.0 (iOS 14.0) you can use `@AppStorage` property wrapper for such types: `Bool, Int, Double, String, URL` and `Data`.
Here is example of usage for storing String value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    static let userNameKey = "user_name"
    
    @AppStorage(Self.userNameKey) var userName: String = "Unnamed"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(userName)
            
            Button("Change automatically ") {
                userName = "Ivor"
            }
            
            Button("Change manually") {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue("John", forKey: Self.userNameKey)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are declaring `userName` property with default value which isn't going to the `UserDefaults` itself. When you first mutate it, application will write that value into the `UserDefaults` and automatically update the view with the new value.

Also there is possibility to set custom `UserDefaults` provider if needed via `store` parameter like this:

```
@AppStorage(Self.userNameKey, store: UserDefaults.shared) var userName: String = "Mike"
```

and

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static var shared: UserDefaults {
        let combined = UserDefaults.standard
        combined.addSuite(named: "group.myapp.app")
        return combined
    }
}
```

Notice: ff that value will change outside of the Application (let's say manually opening the plist file and changing value), View will not receive that update.

P.S. Also there is new Extension on `View` which adds `func defaultAppStorage(_ store: UserDefaults) -> some View` which allows to change the storage used for the View. This can be helpful if there are a lot of `@AppStorage` properties and setting custom storage to each of them is cumbersome to do.

Comment: Friendly hint... you're mentioning beta software in a public forum. Better to discuss beta software in Apple Dev Forums.

Comment: I disagree. This is good place and your comment is already outdated

Comment: There's also a possibility to use `@AppStorage` with other types (like `Array`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62563773/8697793)

Comment: I want dat. Thanks! Great syntactic sugar.

Comment: I don't understand how to get something at a given key from user defaults in swiftui. What exactly should one use?

Answer (score 28):

The code below adapts Mohammad Azam's excellent solution in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV-OdfQhStM):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userDefaultsManager = UserDefaultsManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: self.$userDefaultsManager.firstToggle) {
                Text("First Toggle")
            }

            Toggle(isOn: self.$userDefaultsManager.secondToggle) {
                Text("Second Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

class UserDefaultsManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstToggle: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstToggle") {
        didSet { UserDefaults.standard.set(self.firstToggle, forKey: "firstToggle") }
    }

    @Published var secondToggle: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "secondToggle") {
        didSet { UserDefaults.standard.set(self.secondToggle, forKey: "secondToggle") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, create a property wrapper that will allow us to easily make the link between your Settings class and UserDefaults:

```
import Foundation

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<Value: Codable> {    
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value

    var value: Value {
        get {
            let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key)
            let value = data.flatMap { try? JSONDecoder().decode(Value.self, from: $0) }
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, create a data store that holds your settings:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class DataStore: BindableObject {
    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataStore, Never>()

    @UserDefault(key: "Settings", defaultValue: [])
    var settings: [Settings] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in your view, access your settings:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataStore: DataStore

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $settings.space) {
            Text("\(settings.space)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the final class it errors saying that it can't access Settings so when I move the struct in so it can it then errors saying "Generic struct 'UserDefault' requires that 'DataStore.Settings' conform to 'Decodable', Generic struct 'UserDefault' requires that 'DataStore.Settings' conform to 'Encodable', Initializer 'init(key:defaultValue:)' requires that 'DataStore.Settings' conform to 'Decodable', and Initializer 'init(key:defaultValue:)' requires that 'DataStore.Settings' conform to 'Encodable'" and when using the dataStore var when it tries accessing settings it says they can't find it.

Comment: @SmushyTaco did you get this worked out?  I am having the same issue, when BindableObject went away, my code all broke, and I am now stuck trying to work with multiple settings in UserDefaults.

Answer (score 3):

I'm supriced no one wrote the new way, anyway, Apple migrated to this method now and you don't need all the old code, you can read and write to it like this:

```
@AppStorage("example") var example: Bool = true
```

that's the equivalent to read/write in the old `UserDefaults`. You can use it as a regular variable.

Comment: `I'm supriced no one wrote the new way` Actually @AppStorage has been mentioned  already in some of the other answers.

Comment: @EricAya you are right, it was mentioned, I prob. read too fast. However they put extra unnecessary code, this is more concise

Answer (score 2):

If you are persisting a one-off struct such that a property wrapper is overkill, you can encode it as JSON. When decoding, use an empty `Data` instance for the no-data case.

```swift
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: Profile? = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Profile.self, from: UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "profile") ?? Data()) {
        didSet { UserDefaults.standard.set(try? JSONEncoder().encode(profile), forKey: "profile") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another great solution is to use the unofficial static subscript API of `@propertyWrapper` instead of the `wrappedValue` which simplifies a lot the code. Here is the definition:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<Value> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value

    init(wrappedValue: Value, _ key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = wrappedValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { fatalError("Called wrappedValue getter") }
        set { fatalError("Called wrappedValue setter") }
    }

    static subscript(
        _enclosingInstance instance: Preferences,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Preferences, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Preferences, Self>
    ) -> Value {
        get {
            let wrapper = instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath]
            return instance.userDefaults.value(forKey: wrapper.key) as? Value ?? wrapper.defaultValue
        }

        set {
            instance.objectWillChange.send()
            let key = instance[keyPath: storageKeyPath].key
            instance.userDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can define your settings object like this:

```swift
final class Settings: ObservableObject {
  let userDefaults: UserDefaults

  init(defaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
    userDefaults = defaults
  }

  @UserDefaults("yourKey") var yourSetting: SettingType
  ...
}
```

However, be careful with this kind of implementation. Users tend to put all their app settings in one of such object and use it in every view that depends on one setting. This can result in slow down caused by too many unnecessary `objectWillChange` notifications in many view.
You should definitely separate concerns by breaking down your settings in many small classes.

The `@AppStorage` is a great native solution but the drawback is that is kind of break the unique source of truth paradigm as you must provide a default value for every property.