# How to seamlessly wrap @Published variables with a UserDefaults propertyWrapper

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been looking for the perfect UserDefaults wrapper that

- seamlessly encodes and decodes Data objects from storage
- works with @Published

My starting point was this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57982560/1346618), but it uses `object:forKey` which doesn't work with custom objects (encoding URLs is always non-trivial for me).

My idea is to be able to use it like so:

```swift
struct Server: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable, Hashable { /* vars */ }

class ServerPickerViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Published(wrappedValue: Server.defaultServers.first!,
             type: Server.self,
             key: "currentServer")
  var currentServer: Server?

}
```

To achieve this, I modified the code from @VictorKushnerov's answer:

```swift
import Combine

private var cancellables = [String: AnyCancellable]()

extension Published {
  init<T: Encodable & Decodable>(wrappedValue defaultValue: T, type: T.Type, key: String) {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      var value: T
      if
        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key),
        let decodedVal = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) {
        value = decodedVal
      } else {
        value = defaultValue
      }

        self.init(initialValue: value) // <-- Error

        cancellables[key] = projectedValue.sink { val in
          let encoder = JSONEncoder()
          let encodedVal = encoder.encode(val) // <-- Error
          UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedVal, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

There are currently two errors I can't get through, which are the following:

- `Cannot convert value of type 'T' to expected argument type 'Value'` it still relying on the underlying `@Published`'s `Value` generic type, I wish I could override that with my type T.
- `Instance method 'encode' requires that 'Published<Value>.Publisher.Output' (aka 'Value') conform to 'Encodable'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your compilation errors by using `where Value : Codable` to restrict your extension. Then, you can get rid of your `T` generic altogether (& you don't have to use the `type` argument either):

```
extension Published where Value : Codable {
  init(wrappedValue defaultValue: Value, key: String) {
      let decoder = JSONDecoder()
      var value: Value
      if
        let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key),
        let decodedVal = try? decoder.decode(Value.self, from: data) {
        value = decodedVal
      } else {
        value = defaultValue
      }

        self.init(initialValue: value)

        cancellables[key] = projectedValue.sink { val in
          let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            do {
                let encodedVal = try encoder.encode(val)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedVal, forKey: key)
            } catch {
                print(error)
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This being said, I'd probably take the path instead of creating a custom property wrapper instead that wraps `@AppStorage` instead of extending `@Published`

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: not fully, I'm waiting some more for more answers before I give it the green checkmark.